# Configuration for vue-resource root and authorization

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm looking at the following documentation for vue-resource that describes how to set up configuration:  https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/config.md

It says to set your headers with a common authorization value:

```
 Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic YXBpOnBhc3N3b3Jk';
```

I am guessing this "Basic YXBpOnBhc3N3b3Jk" value is just an example, but what is this value for, and what should one use instead of it?

On the same page, I also see a setting for "root":

```
 Vue.http.options.root = '/root';
```

I understand this to mean the web URL for the web app.  However, why does vue-resource need me to tell it this value?  What does it use it for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By adding headers to the `Vue.http.headers.common` object you are telling vue-resource to add these headers in every request.

You can also add headers to each request:

```
http({
 url: '/someUrl', 
 method: 'GET',
 headers: {
   Authorization: 'Basic YXBpOnBhc3N3b3Jk'
 }
})
```

About the value for the `Authorization` header in the example: It is a base64-encoded string with username/password.

```
window.atob('YXBpOnBhc3N3b3Jk') // => "api:password"
```

If you need to use basic authentication when using vue-resource, you should provide your own username/password.

Note that everyone who is using you application can view the username/password.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication for more information about basic authentiaction.

The root-property could be the main endpoint to your REST-service.
Instead of:

```
http({
 url: 'http://api.domain.com/v1/someRoute'
});
```

You could set the root endpoint with:

```
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://api.domain.com/v1'

// will call http://api.domain.com/v1/someRoute
http({
 url: '/someRoute'
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the great response :)

Comment: Important to note, if you do an `http` request to `'/someRoute'`, it will *override* the `root` setting.  You must request `'someRoute'` in order for it to use the root you set.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

If you want set header auth in global way use the inceptor

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function(request, next) {

    request.headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic abcd' //Base64
    request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    next()
});
```

and use option credentials:

```
Vue.http.options.credentials = true;
```

Comment: docs have been updated: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md#interceptors