# Vue.js2 - How to set a global header from a nested component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I made vue project via **Vue cli** with a **simple-webpack** structure.
I use **Vue resources** and **vue routes** and an API that sends me authorized token when I send the correct credentials for the user.

how can I make the token to sit in the header of all the next requests this user will make.

right now I found a way to save the token to the local storage and send it in the header for each request
{headers: {Authorization: localStorage.Authorization}}
but I found it not dry and very frustrating.

moreover i'v found the `Vue.http.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'token...'` - and I want to know how to implement the token from the login request to this global instance.

I've also find this approach - `Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {// setting the header});`
but couldn't understand when should I implement this or how to send the data from the component to this object.

Comment: Look at the 2nd answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315389/configuration-for-vue-resource-root-and-authorization

Comment: As I mention in the question. I've seen this approach, how I configure  `Vue.http.interceptors.push((request, next) => {// setting the header});` from the component?

Comment: These config overrides are global, so you'll have to set it outside of all components scope and it will apply to all XHR calls (for example - in app.js file)

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not clear, I understand what you say and yet don't know how to send the data (the token) to this config from the component. as I mention in the last sentence of my question.

Answer (score 1):

After big research, I've found out that Vue-resource is no longer an **official** package and instead **Axios** is.

*Vue resource package is still working and will keep being maintained by their creators.*

I've migrated to **Axios** ajax handling package and use the axios configuration and it worked as magic.
I've added this line to the main.js file.

**axios.defaults.headers.common['Auth'] = localStorage.Auth;**

`import axios from 'axios'
    import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
    [...]// somecode
    axios.defaults.headers.common['Auth'] = localStorage.Auth;
    [...]//some code`

then from the login method -
in the `axios.post('url').then(response=>{ // set the localstorage})`

this will update the local storage and same as v-bind directive the global config will be updated and from now on the headers of all the requests will have this token.